# How to take formatted input in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, io

I have to take input for an array in c. Sample input would be something like this -

```
33 33 2
000000000000000000000010000000000
000000000000000000000111000000000
000000000000000000001110100000000
000000000000000000011111111000000
000000000000000000001011100000000
000000000000000000000111000000000
000000000000000000000010000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
011111111111110000000000000000000
011011111111110000000000000000000
011111111110110000000000000000000
011111111111110000000000000000000
011111111111110000000000000000000
011111011111110000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Here, 33 and 33 are m rows and n colums. 2 is the number of patterns in the integer grid. While the rest is a matrix.

How would I go about enter this matrix into an array in C. Having problems with it for quite some time. This is my current code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int **array;

    int m = atoi(argv[1]);
    int n = atoi(argv[2]);

    array = calloc(m, sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        array[i] = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            /*Code to get input from*/
        }
        
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        free(array[i]);
    }

    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: read a string with scanf("%s", buff). this will read until next line then you can convert each character to the number you want

Comment: First of all: check if argc is correct and act accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are passing the data (your sample input) via command line using something like

```
./program $(<data.txt)
```

You can get the input with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        array[i][j] = argv[4 + i][j]; // Get the value as character
    }
}
```

And print with

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("%c", array[i][j]); // Print the character
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

or (as pointed out by @tshiono in comments)

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        array[i][j] = argv[4 + i][j] - '0'; // Get the value as integer
    }
}
```

and print with

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("%d", array[i][j]); // Print the integer
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I would use meaningful names

```
int rows = atoi(argv[1]);
int cols = atoi(argv[2]);
```

instead of

```
int m = atoi(argv[1]);
int n = atoi(argv[2]);
```

and

```
for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
```

instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
```

Comment: Where did OP say that they were using Linux and bash? AFAIK `$(<data.txt)` is not C language ;-)

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes you are right, that's why I said _"using something like ..."_ I have no idea how is done in Windows :D